# Error in ng serve after installing npm angular/cli

Tags: node.js, angular, npm

I am a beginner in learning nodejs and angular. I have installed node and created a node project which was working fine. Then I did "npm install -g angular-cli" and after that i did ng new client and inside client when i do "ng serve" i am getting the following error:

```
The "@angular/compiler-cli" package was not properly installed.
Error: The "@angular/compiler-cli" package was not properly installed.
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Subhasree\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\angular-cli\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\index.js:14:11)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Subhasree\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\angular-cli\models\webpack-configs\typescript.js:3:17)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Subhasree\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\angular-cli\models\webpack-configs\index.js:9:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Subhasree\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\angular-cli\models\webpack-config.js:4:25)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Subhasree\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\angular-cli\tasks\serve.js:11:24)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Subhasree\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\angular-cli\commands\serve.run.js:6:15)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Class.run (C:\Users\Subhasree\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\angular-cli\commands\serve.js:67:16)
    at Class.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Subhasree\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\angular-cli\ember-cli\lib\models\command.js:134:17)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:109:7)
```

Comment: i have been trying multiple times since yesterday to install with "npm install -g angular-cli" and "npm install -g @angular/cli" but the same error on "ng serve" everytime.

Answer (score 0):

You may have older versions.

See the instructions here and see if that helps: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-1.0-update

The steps are basically:

1. Uninstall old version
2. Update node/npm if necessary
3. Install new version

The link provides specifics for each of these steps along with appropriate commands.

Comment: Thank you. I did all the steps above. now "ng --version" gives 

@angular/cli: 1.2.0
node: 6.10.3
os: win32 x64
@angular/cli: 1.2.0

ng new testapp  :  gives "You cannot use the new command inside an Angular CLI project."  What is the error now.

Comment: The folder you are in already contains an Angular project. Just create a different folder, navigate to that folder, and try again.

Comment: Where you able to successfully create a project?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple solution to that and it works like charm.

- `cd` into your project directory `cd client`.
- Run `npm install` or `yarn install`, wait for it to successfully execute
- Run your `ng serve`.

I hope this helps and much more easier

Answer (score 0):

Run these two commands:

```
npm uninstall --save-dev angular-cli
npm install --save-dev @angular/cli@latest
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to run this : npm install --save-dev @angular/cli@latest